# Struct type serialization problem in c#

Tags: c#, serialization, struct

I have implemented a sqlserver Session state mechanism to save my session in database but I am getting a error of Session state serialization. And my class contains struct types and I have added the `Serializable` attribute on top of that.

Comment: What else does the struct contain? If it itself holds references to types that are **not** serializable, then you can't serialize it.

Comment: Is your class itself Serializable? Not just the struct?

Comment: "i am getting a error of Session state serialization" ... *which* error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Serializable tag to all classes that will be stored in your session.

Answer (score 0):

Try impelementing ISerializable interface